# Javascript Click Event Pushing Multiple Duplicates to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

In recreating the Simon game, I am trying to push a click event to an array and then immediately test that Array in a nested function. On the first pass it seems to work.

However, on the third run the array does not seem to clear.

The screen shot below also shows that each input is printed multiple times to the console.

[image]

Full code pen here - https://codepen.io/jhc1982/pen/NwQZRw?editors=1010

Quick example:

```
function userMoves() {
  var userInput = [];

document.getElementById("red").addEventListener("click", function(){
  userInput.push("red");
  testington();
}); 

$(".red").mousedown(function(event){
  redAudio.play();
  $(".red").css("background-color", "red");
});

$(".red").mouseup(function(){
  $(".red").css("background-color", "#990000");
});

function testington(){
 if (userInput.length == pattern.length) {
   for (var i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
     if (userInput[i] !== pattern[i]) {
         alert("Game Over");
     } else if (i === userInput.length -1 && userInput[i] === pattern[i]) {
        userInput = emptyArr;
        simonMoves();
        console.log("user input is ",userInput);
     } else {
       continue;
    }
   }    
  } 
 }
}
```

I am sure it is something really obvious but have been stuck for hours.

Comment: This is because of your for loop `for (var i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {`. It logs multiple times because it loops multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be that you are assigning the click events every time the userMoves execute. That means every time the function is called the event is added to the elements, so after two calls to userMoves() when you click on red the event is executed twice, after three calls it is executed three times, etc.

The code that adds the event listener should be out of the userMoves function. The testington function should also be out of userMoves, which would get much simpler:

```
function userMoves() {
    $("#score-text").text(level);
    userInput = [];
}
```

Here's a Pen with working code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ppzqyY

Comment: Thanks man. I really, really, really need to get my head around closures.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `break;` keyword to after `alert("Game over");`

```
function testington(){
 if (userInput.length == pattern.length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
   if (userInput[i] !== pattern[i]) {
    alert("Game Over");

    break; // Break the loop

   } else if (i === userInput.length -1 && userInput[i] === pattern[i]) {
    userInput = emptyArr;
    simonMoves();
    console.log("user input is ",userInput);
   } else {
     continue;
   }
  }    
 } 
}
```